# Trying to build a Qt application with VC++ compiler: 'type_traits': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

Why doesn't the compiler find the file? It exists in the VC include directory for VS 14.0.

I've read that in previous versions of Visual Studio, you have had to install a service pack or something, is this a similar case?

I'm using VS 2015 Community.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved by running `vcvarsall.bat` and starting Qt Creator from the same command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in `Visual Studio 2019 Community` with `Qt 6.0.0`
after, searching every forum etc.. and trying the install of `Visual Studio 2015 build tools x64` and `Visual Studio redistributable 2015  x64` (which didn't solve the problem too),
I tried updating `Windows sdk` version from `10.0.18362.0` to `10.0.19041.0` and the problem was SOLVED.
I'm currently using `Visual Studio Community 4.8.03761` if that might help others
so just check that you have `Window sdk version 10` updated and that your compiler is well chosen (I had `mvsc2019_64` and work with `LLVM` etc.. version in build settings) .
hopefully this helps you guys.